# Excel Formula: Current 12 months

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula in excel that will give me a current 12 month table. For example  this month is April. I want a formula that gives me 12 months back from April in the exact format as show in the table below. For next month it will be May, and 12 months back from may without having to adjust any dates.

```
Month
5/1/2015
6/1/2015
8/1/2015
9/1/2015
10/1/2015
11/1/2015
12/1/2015
1/1/2016
2/1/2016
3/1/2016
4/1/2016
```

Thank you

Comment: In cell A1: `=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-11,1)` and then in cell A2 and copied down to A12: `=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1)`.  It will auto-update the months when the current month changes.  Format the cells as desired.

Comment: in one formula. Put this in your first cell  `=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-12+ROW(1:1),1)` and drag down 12 rows.  Then format as desired.

Comment: Do you want the formula to skip the third month, too?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and copy down 11 rows

```
=EDATE((TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())+1),ROW(A1)-12)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you number the months in column b starting from b2 =0 to  b13=11
And row 1 has headers
A2 formula =EOMONTH(today(),b2-1)+1
A3 formula = EOMONTH(today(),b3-1)+1

Etc.

EOMONTH will give you the last day of any month.  So if we start with today() it will give you the last day of the current month, but if we count back 1 month (b2-1).  It will give you the last day of last month.  So we add 1 day to it and you get the first day of each month.

Hope this helps :)